# How can I Stretch the viewPager Area?

Tags: android

I setup a viewPager area in my activity.
Is it possible for the viewPager area stretch to the full screen as I want to eliminate the big border in it...
I can't seem to resize it manually

[image]

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your host activity, the viewpager itself or the viewpager fragments might have a margin or padding added to them. Simply remove these and you should get the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks, I moved the padding to the activity and it works perfectly!